# python-usbtmc insufficient permissions. Raspberry Pi 4, Python3

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, udev

I'm trying to use python-usbtmc to connect to my Agilent oscilloscope.  I managed to use the readme on github to get it working, but am experiencing errors since restarting my Pi.

The output from lsusb:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04d9:0007 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 023: ID 0957:0588 Agilent Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The device I'm looking at is 0959:0588.

My udev rules file:

```
# USBTMC instruments

# Agilent DSO1052B
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0x0957", ATTR{idProduct}=="0x0588", GROUP="usbtmc", MODE="0666"
```

Note: I've also tried with ATTRS.

My Python3 code:

```
>>> import usbtmc
>>> inst = usbtmc.Instrument(0x0957, 0x0588)
>>> print(inst.ask("*IDN")
```

which returns:

```
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

When plugged in and powered-on, the scope is added to /dev/usbtmc0. Using ls -all, I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/dev $ ls -all | grep usbtmc*
crw-rw-rw-   1 root usbtmc    180, 176 Jun 11 14:13 usbtmc0
```

To me, those permissions look wrong, based on the udev file... but I'm a bit unexperienced in that area to be sure.  When I run python as sudo, it works as expected (though additionally, the device is listed differently in list_resources():

```
>>> import usbtmc
>>> usbtmc.list_resources()
['USB::2391::1416::CN56489391\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00::INSTR']
>>> inst = usbtmc.Instrument(2391, 1416)
>>> print(inst.ask("*IDN?"))
AGILENT TECHNOLOGIES,DSO1052B,CN56489391,01.20.00 SP4
```

I'd be grateful if someone could suggest what I can try to further investigate this issue, and possibly resolve it.  Thanks!

Comment: You should probably use `ATTR` instead of `ATTRS`.

Comment: Also make sure you run `systemd restart systemd-udevd` after adding / modifying rules (if you want to test without rebooting).

Comment: @TomYan  Thanks for these suggestions.  I've tried with ATTR, to no avail.  I do use the `systemctl restart systemd-udevd`, but have also rebooted.

Comment: I've amended my question, as using `MODE="0666"` changed the group and permissions to `crw-rw-rw-`.  I still have the same permissions error.

Comment: So what exactly does `usbtmc.list_resources()` give you if you are non-root?

Comment: And have you tried `MODE="0666"` with `ATTRS` instead of `ATTR`?